# php script for star rating in admin panel?

Tags: php

I am new to php.
I have a site which have admin section.here i want admin to rate the products he is having and that rating should be stored in database.

I don't have any idea about this.
Please anybody help me with some examples.

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't have taken the job.

Comment: What do you mean you have no idea about this? Do you have any code for the admin panel?

Comment: ya in admin panel im listing all the products...here i want to add star rating to each product........but how to do this??

Comment: Store the star rating in the admin panel and display it?

Answer (score 2):

On a high level this is what you need to do.

In your database, add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD COLUMN `star_rating` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Store a value that the user has clicked on, which will be either 0 to 5.

On output, you can output X stars with something such as the following:

```
<strong>Rating:</strong> <?php echo str_repeat('<img src="/star.png" alt="*" />', $row['star_rating']) ?>
```

.. where `$row` is a `mysql_fetch_assoc()` result from `SELECT * FROM products`.

This is however all extremely basic and will be covered off in even the simplest of PHP/MySQL tutorials, you should really learn the language.

Comment: @daGrevis I don't see any reason to over-complicate such a simple task ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by many ways..
one way is  you allow user to rate product and you can store ratings in one db column which entered by admin and then you can always print it.